# Minimum index is not showing when it is called

Tags: python, list, indexing

We are to make that lets the user enter the total rainfall for each 12 months into a list. The program should calculate and display the total rainfall for the year, the average monthly rainfall

problem:The maximum value did great but the minimum value is stuck at 0

code:

```
Rainfall=[0]*13
i=1
total=0
print("Enter the Rainfall each month")
while i<=12:
    print('Month #',i, ': ',end=' ')
    Rainfall[i]=float(input())
    total+=Rainfall[i]

    i+=1
ave=total/12

High = max (Rainfall)
Low = min(Rainfall)


print("total Amount= ",total)
print("Average Average Amount {:0.2f}".format(ave))


print ("The months with the highest value are : ")
print ([i for i, j in enumerate(Rainfall) if j == High])
print ("The months with the Lowest value are : ")
print ([i for i, j in enumerate(Rainfall) if j == Low])

output:Enter the Rainfall each month
Month # 1 :  1
Month # 2 :  1
Month # 3 :  399
Month # 4 :  900
Month # 5 :  900
Month # 6 :  900
Month # 7 :  900
Month # 8 :  2323
Month # 9 :  42
Month # 10 :  100
Month # 11 :  10000
Month # 12 :  10000
total Amount=  26466.0
Average Average Amount 2205.50
The months with the highest value are : 
[11, 12]
The months with the Lowest value are : 
[0]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: You have created a list of 13 elements for 12 months. Then you are filling the list from index `1` isntead of zero. Minimum will then always be `0`.

Comment: it's my precaution so that the month output is not showing 0 - 11 instead of 1 - 12. is there another way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't populate the first index in your list `Rainfall` since your loop starts from i=1 but the first index of the list is 0 (and it's value is 0).

Try this:

```
Rainfall=[0]*12
i=0
print("Enter the Rainfall each month")
while i<len(Rainfall):
    print('Month #',i, ': ',end=' ')
    Rainfall[i]=float(input())
    i+=1

total = sum(Rainfall)
ave=total/len(Rainfall)

High = max (Rainfall)
Low = min(Rainfall)


print("total Amount= ",total)
print("Average Average Amount {:0.2f}".format(ave))


print ("The months with the highest value are : ")
print ([i+1 for i, j in enumerate(Rainfall) if j == High])
print ("The months with the Lowest value are : ")
print ([i+1 for i, j in enumerate(Rainfall) if j == Low])
```

Comment: Thankyou it works, but i'm just wondering is there any precaution so that the months is not showing as 0 - 11 but instead it will show 1 - 12 ?

Comment: Yes, I've updated the solution. Just show the months as `i+1` instead of `i`

Comment: I will do my best!

Answer (score 0):

Your array has 13 elements (not 12). Arrays starts at index 0 but you started to fill it from 1.

Rainfall[0] is always 0

Tweak your code. Change

```
Rainfall=[0]*12
i=0

....

while i<12
...
print('Month #',i+1, ': ',end=' ')
...
```